# Meaning of "Produced her Don more heirs at love than law"

Tags: meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

From *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_First)*:

> This heathenish cross restored the breed again,
>        Ruin'd its blood, but much improved its flesh;
>   For from a root the ugliest in Old Spain
>        Sprung up a branch as beautiful as fresh;
>   The sons no more were short, the daughters plain:
>        But there's a rumour which I fain would hush,
>   'T is said that Donna Julia's grandmamma
>   **Produced her Don more heirs at love than law**.

Does this imply that she had extramarital relations, and these heirs had other fathers?

Answer (score 3):

The last paragraph of the question understands the line correctly: according to the rumour, more of Julia’s uncles and aunts were illegitimate (‘heirs at love’) than legitimate (‘heirs at law’). The *OED* says:

> **heir-at-law** *n.* the person who succeeds another by right of blood in the enjoyment of his property

This phrase was popularized by the comedy [*The Heir at Law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heir_at_Law) by [George Colman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Colman_the_Younger) which opened in London in 1797 and would have been familiar to Byron and his readers in 1819 when the first part of *Don Juan* was published.

The phrase ‘heir at love’ is parallel to ‘heir at law’, but this is ironic because if a child were known to be illegitimate, they would be no heir at all.